# Python Free String Passed to Function

Tags: python, function, memory, args

Is there some way in python to manually free memory allocated for a string while some other variable still references it? I would like to free a string passed to a function inside of the function.

```
def use_string(s):
  do_something_with_s(s)
  #can I free memory used for s here?
  do_other_things_that_dont_need_s()

my_string = "hi there."*100000
use_string(my_string)
do_some_other_things_that_dont_need_my_string()
```

As I understand, both s (in the context of use_string) and my_string will be referencing the same immutable string object, which can only be freed when no variables point to it. Is this ture?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's unnecessary (Python has a capable GC), and if there are other references you would run the risk of accessing freed memory (this is a **Very Bad Thing™**).

Comment: I was wondering part because I had an incredibly long string that I no longer needed after I had a certain permutation of it, and part because of curiosity. Thanks :D

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the long string. As I said, Python has a very capable GC that will deal with these matters so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Python objects are passed as a reference passed by value (ie you can't change the reference, but you can change the contents of the referenced object unless the object is immutable), you cannot change the reference a caller directly passes into the function from inside the function.

If you need to change/free the string, you need to wrap it in a class so you can change the only reference to the string which is inside the object. I'd recommend taking a deep breath before obfuscating the code like this, but when you really need it, you really need it.

This example is designed only to in minimal code show the concept, not to show how to do it in a beautiful way :)

```py
def use_string(wrap):
  print wrap.s           # Prints 'olle'
  wrap.s = None          # Resets the reference
  print wrap.s           # Prints 'None'

class wrapper(object):
  pass

a = wrapper()
a.s = "olle"
print a.s                # Prints 'olle'
use_string(a)
print a.s                # Prints 'None'
```

Comment: "Since parameters are passed by value, you can't change a string that is directly passed in to the function" : sorry but that's just plain wrong. The only reason you can't "change a string" because it's immutable, and your code snippet proves that a function can indeed mutate an object passed as argument, which wouldn't be the case if it was "passed by value".

Comment: Though I appreciate every responders thoughtful advice, this was the only response that actually offered a solution, rather than saying you just shouldn't do it. It seems more useful to me to say, "this is how you do something, but be careful", then to say "the problem you trying to solve probably doesn't exist".

Comment: @dmlicht - this works because `a.s` is the only reference to the string in the first place. If you initialize `a.s` with anything else, that original reference still exists; all you've done is waste time wrapping the string, and restricting its use to a function custom-written to accept the wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's what the [`del` keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is for.
Whether it actually makes sense to do this in a garbage collected language is another matter.

Comment: I couldn't fully understand its usage from the link; does this free up the memory or just remove the reference?

Comment: It removes the reference. In CPython (the default python you get from python.org) the object is collected and the memory freed once the reference count reaches zero. 
So in your example the memory would probably not be freed since there is most likely another reference to the string outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Using `del s` in the function will remove the reference in that scope.

If it's the last reference to the string object, it may then be freed. (In the example here, it won't, since the global `my_string` still refers to it.)

Comment: Ahh that's what I figured, do you know if there is any way to actually free it? Thanks for your response :)

Comment: it *may* then be freed (although the language references makes no guarantee of when this will actually happen)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Python's garbage collector will free the memory when there are no more references to it.

If you want more details: http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection

Comment: Thanks for your response! I would like to free the string passed to the function while in the function. If I understand correctly when the function first executes, there will be two references to the string object. One outside the scope of the function and one inside. While in the function, I can remove the reference from inside, but there will still be a reference that I can't access from within the function, right?

Comment: No, you won't be able to modify the reference from within the function. I'd be careful with this kind of thing, there's a whole class of errors caused by doing this type of thing called "dangling-pointer errors."

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you can either

```
my_string = "hi there."*100000
use_string(my_string)
del my_string
```

which allows the garbage collector to release the memory initially allocated for `my_string`, or

```
use_string( "hi there." * 100000 )
```

in which case the only reference to the string was the function-local variable, and the memory will be freed once the function returns.

Under no circumstances should you (even if you were able to) deallocate the memory inside the function, since you have no idea if other code held a reference to that memory and might try to use it.